# permission denied to start tomcat as root

Tags: linux, centos, tomcat, java, yum

I just started using CentOS.

**I install Java**

```
yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel
```

**Added a user:**

```
$useradd supersite
```

**Downloaded tomcat:**

```
$wget http://apache.mirror.anlx.net/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.42/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.42.zip
$unzip apache-tomcat-7.0.42.zip -d tomcat7
```

**Created service configuration:**

```
$ cd /etc/init.d
$ edit tomcat7-supersite
```

I copied the file from [here](http://www.vlad-yatsenko.eu/2011/04/plesk-apache-mod_jk-tomcat-good-relationship/).

However, when I try to run as root user (I see that I am root@myip)

```
service tomcat7-supersite start
```

I get:

```
env: /etc/init.d/tomcat7-supersite: Permission denied
```

Why?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The file `/etc/init.d/tomcat7-supersite` lacks the execute permission. You need to run

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/tomcat7-supersite
```